# Why is charge surface uniform while circuit is open?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, conductors, batteries

[image]

The above image shows surface charge distribution for open circuit(ends not connected). I point out different regions by numbers.

The surface charge distribution is mostly uniform(maybe, not near the bends, but in Region 1 and 2, much likely uniform). I wonder why it's the same distribution density in 1 and 2 region. Let me explain why. In region 1, electric field is stronger than in region 2. Then we can say that in region 1, more electrons will leave region 1, then to enter  it. This is because in the end of region 1(closer to battery), E is stronger, then in the beginning. So more electrons will leave it then to enter it at some duration time `t`. Because of this, positive ions produced, and repelled from each other, hence surface charges. If we imagine it in terms of numbers, let's say 16 electrons left, but 8 entered, so total 8 electron were lost, so 8 positive ions on the surface. Now in Region 2, no chance 16 electrons would be leaving it, as E is weaker, so if in Region 1, 16 left, for sure, much less will leave it here. Let's say 8. This also implies even less electrons will enter it, probably 4. We now see we're left with 4 electrons overally leaving Region 2, so on the surface, we must have less surface charges.

Or more interesting question is, in region 1, as we know, E is stronger by the battery than in Region 2. So in order to make E = 0 in both region 1 and 2, we need different opposite magnitude of E in 1 and 2. As an example, in region 1, at some point, E = 40, while in Region 2, at some point, E = 20. Now, if surface charges in Region 1 and 2 produce the same magnitude of opposite E of "20", we won't get E=0 in Region 1. So we must have more surface charge density in region 1.

But I don't understand why on the image, it shows the same. If you say they don't account for it, I will say you're wrong, because there's a next image where circuit is closed and they actually show that in Region 1, density of surface charges is bigger. [See here](https://ibb.co/hd3n5dP)

Answer (score 0):

I imagined the equipotential map of electric scalar potential (in unit of volt) as follows.
[image: Imagined hand written equipotential lines]

Assuming that this handwritten imaginary figure is an approximation of the real solution, the spacing of the equipotential lines near the conducting lines is not even. Therefore, the statement "The surface charge distribution is mostly uniform" is true, but very, very rough.

Comment: How would you explain without equipotential ? Meaning if you follow my explanation and logic, where am I making a mistake ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything mistake with your description.
Since like electricity repels and unlike electricity attracts, your explanation may be possible.

Two wires in an open circuit form a weak capacitor.
I don't know how to rigorously solve the phenomenon of electrical charge transfer, I thought [the explanation of the RC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit) in Wikipedia might be helpful.